# Angular Options que se vayan desapareciendo de la lista si las selecciono

Tags: angular

Quiero que cada vez que yo selecciono una opcion, esta se vaya desapareciendo de la lista.
[image: Form]

[image: Options]

```js
public resRelation: IDataOfKey<string> = {};
public relateElements = data // contiene las opciones de respuesta
public onChangeRelate(event: number, term: string): void {
        const key: string = '' + event;
        //this.onSearchIndex(this.elementRelated, parseInt(key));
        const data: IDataOfKey<string> = {};
        data[key] = term;
        if (this.resRelation[key]) {this.resRelation[key] = term; }
        if (!this.resRelation[key]) {this.resRelation = Object.assign(this.resRelation, data); }
        this.form.patchValue({
            lesson_activity_id: this.item.id,
            answer: this.resRelation
        });
    }
```

```html
<section class="w-100-p " *ngFor="let option of relateElements">
                <div fxLayout="row">
                    <p>{{option.term}}</p>
                </div>
                <mat-form-field class="w-100-p">
                    <mat-label>Seleccione</mat-label>
                    <mat-select (valueChange)="onChangeRelate($event, option.term)">
                        <mat-option [value]="value.id" *ngFor="let value of elementRelated">{{value.definition}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </section>
```

relateElements = Items opciones de respuesta.

Angular 11 @Angular/forms
@Angular/material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un un arreglo que contenga los elementos seleccionados y validar que, si están en el arreglo, no se puedan seleccionar.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let preguntas of ['Q1', 'Q2']; let i = index">
  {{ preguntas }}
  <select (change)="agregarId($event, i)">
    <!-- La primera opción no se puede seleccionar -->
    <option disabled selected></option>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let opcion of opciones">
      <option
        [disabled]="idSeleccionados.includes(opcion.id)"
        [value]="opcion.id"
      >
        {{ opcion.valor }}
      </option>
    </ng-container>
  </select>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</ng-container>
```

La lógica del componenete es bastante sencilla.

```js
  idSeleccionados = [];

  agregarId(e, i) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    //Uso *1 por que generé los ids como number y al comparar 
    // es más fácil hacer la conversión de una vez. 
    this.idSeleccionados[i] = e.target.value * 1;
  }
```

Este es el [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ibqxpo?file=src/app/app.component.html).

> Con respecto a los componentes de material desing, puedes adaptar este ejemplo.